# Can I reposition the induction coil in a Qi charger

Tags: wireless, charging

I have recently bought a Qi wireless charging case for my phone as a car mount that I was bought for Christmas had a Qi charger build into it. Both work well, but are the coils are misaligned by about half an inch.

I've taken the charger apart and can see the coil and the circuitry, the PCB cannot be moved, but I could reposition the coil. However the ends of the coils that are soldered onto the PCB are not long enough.

Can I splice in some similar gauge plastic coated wire so that there is enough slack to be able to move the coil, or does it need to be a specific wire type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lengthen the leads with whatever wire you have, as long as you aren't going to try to lengthen them by dozens of meters.  But I'd ask first, is it necessary?  I have a wireless charger for my phone, and misalignment doesn't seem to affect it much if at all.  As long as the phone is reasonably positioned, it charges.

Comment: Yes, in order to get the phone to charge it has to either be upside down (and run the risk of it slipping out) or pushed so far up that it looks ridiculous) charging pad is about 1.5" further up the body of the phone than the reciever. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Okay, then there isn't an issue lengthening the leads but a couple of inches.  Best of luck!

Comment: Gave it a go this evening. Went flawlessly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To give a direct answer to your question; not a pro or hobbyist sort of in between. I have worked on induction projects many variations. It is possible to lengthen then leads a bit, enough to reach the optimal position your going for. The lengthening of the leads will cause a disruption in quality of resonance. If your only repositioning the Tx coil around the case above mentioned method is suggested, but extending it otherwise may alter already shaky quality for you.